# Jquery script execution order DataTables

Tags: jquery, django, datatables

I am populating page with html loaded from controler by calling

```
$("#test").load("{% url 'simple_dataframe' %}");
```

'simple_dataframe' is pandas.to_html() method which is returning proper html for datatables jquery.

Next script is:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#df_table').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Which doesnt load properly. I have copied returned html to page and run it with only DataTable jquery and it runs fine. So its not related to malformed html. 
I think its something to do with the order in which scripts are called.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/jquery.dataTables.css' %}" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="{% static "js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.dataTables.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#test").load("{% url 'simple_dataframe' %}");
    });</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#df_table').DataTable();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because the `load()` call is asynchronous, so you're attempting to create a Datatable on HTML which doesn't yet exist. To fix this, put the `DataTable()` call in the callback of `load()`, like this:

```
$(function () {
  $("#test").load("{% url 'simple_dataframe' %}", function() {
    $('#df_table').DataTable();
  });
});
```